# Recursively return the number of digits divisible by given integer k

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I'm having some trouble getting a program to give the desired output. The program receives two ints: n and k. The program returns the number of digits in n that are cleanly divisible by k (i.e. n%k == 0). See code below.

```
int numDigitsDivk(int n, int k) { // complete this function
    if(n < k)
        return 0;
    else if (n < 10)
        return 1;
    else{
        if(n%k == 0)
            return n%10;
        else
            return numDigitsDivk(n%10, k) + n%10;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "*** Number of digits divisible by k ***" << endl;
    cout << "Number of digits in 123076 is " << numDigitsDivk(123076, 1)
            << endl;
    cout << "Number of even digits in 689201 is " << numDigitsDivk(689201, 2)
            << endl;
    cout << "Number of digits in 6592073 that are divisible by 3 is "
            << numDigitsDivk(6592073, 3) << endl;
}
```

Note that int main() is provided to ensure we get the correct output; we can only change what is in the numDigitsDivk function.

The expected output is as follows:

```
**Number of digits divisible by k**
Number of digits in 123076 is 6
Number of even digits in 689201 is 4
Number of digits in 6592073 that are divisible by 3 is 4
```

However the result I'm getting is not correct. We need to write this function recursively, and I'm pretty sure my issue comes from overthinking the recursive step or misinterpreting what the base case should be (or both).

Comment: You need to evaluate which are divisible in the range, not a single integer.

Comment: @Raymond do you mean do n%10 until n < 10, and at that point implement the recursion?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are only considering the last digit as you are passing `n%10` to the recursion. Since each digit in the given number has to be considered, you gotta pass `n/10` and increment the count every time the last digit of `n` is divisible by `k`

```
int numDigitsDivk(int n, int k) { // complete this function
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    int digit = n%10;
    // if divisible, increment the number of divisible digits
    if (digit%k==0)
        return numDigitsDivk(n/10,k)+1;
    else
        return numDigitsDivk(n/10,k);

}
```

Comment: Ahm you beat me to it. I will delete my answer. Nice answer.

Comment: @Wander3r Ah, this makes more sense, thanks. However since the only step in the base-case here returns 0, all outputs are 1. Shouldn't there be another step in the base case that returns 1?

Comment: @BoolBordan07 Sorry.. didn't get you. Are you telling that it's failing for some number `n`?

Comment: @Wander3r nevermind, made an error (wrote ```if (digit%10 ...``` rather than ```if (digit%k ...```. All looks good. Thanks for your help!